# 'Legs only' when performing a karate kata

Tags: grammar, words

In our karate trainings we often do exercises to perform only leg movements and leg techniques: stances, kicks and jumps from a kata. (Only footwork and foot techniques)

My question is: What would be a proper command in Japanese for that? For instance: `Pin'an sono ichi 'legs only' hajime!`

What I found:

- `足だけ`
- `足のみ`
- `足しか`
- `ただ足`
- `足一人` (suppose it is wrong but was suggested already by someone)

But I am not sure which one will be grammatically correct and would match given circumstances. For clarification (for a level of politeness/formality): let suppose it would be said by the master (先生) to the students.

Comment: Just to help you get an accurate answer, you might want to clarify if your kata is focused literally on legs (like 運足), or kicks. Because 足 is appropriate to express footwork but 蹴り is better for kicks. I have never experienced commands like 運足のみ, 足技のみ, or 蹴りのみ in my career so I'm not qualified to answer your question. Instead my teacher would explain "let's do the next kata without punches" in regular Japanese, and then declare the command.

Comment: @dungarian It is focused on leg movement, stances and kicks.

Comment: I have no experience of karate, but if 'legs only movement' is not a common training in Japan (= you are introducing a new type of training performance), then there is unlikely to be a 'proper' translations. As a general Japanese usage, I guess using a noun alone (e.g. 蹴り) would be natural.

Comment: There already exist modified kata exercises that have common names: 逆 (gyaku) and 裏 (ura). The second one has its own convention when to perform spin and when not. As you noticed, 'legs only' has its own custom that describes which techniques are allowed and which not. If it really is something new, then I'am not seeking for ideal translation but at least one grammatically correct.

Comment: I found reference to たちかた and けりかた, but also 足さばき on the linked site (Stances, Kicking, and Footwork). The third was under miscellaneous and might be what you are looking for, but I would recommend asking someone familiar to the sport. There are also general terms for the upper/lower body (上半身、下半身) which are used for various purposes. https://traditional-karate.com/karate-do/karate-terms/